# Installing SSL with only a .pem file

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, pem

Is it possible to install SSL certificate in Centos (6.5) and apache with just a .pem file? I have been told by the client that they do not have a .crt file or a .key file. It is a wildcard certificate that I need to install in one of the subdomain.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Extensions do not matter.
Usually .crt is used for a certificate in PEM format and .key for the matching key. Both are base64 encoded data with a PEM header like "---- BEGIN CERTIFICATE ---" or "----- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY -----".
But you can put both certificate and key together in a single PEM file and use this inside the certificate and key parameters. But, of course, you have to make sure that your *.pem files really contains both certificate and key.